# Is there evidence that illiquid stocks, held less by institutions, have more price momentum?

Tags: liquidity, momentum

(One of) the standard explanation people gave for momentum is under-reaction of stockholders to firm-specific news.

If this is true, then it seems that these stocks should have more momentum, and also a longer horizon of momentum returns:

1) stocks held less by institutions and more by households (who check their portfolios and news less frequently) 
2) stocks that are less liquid (news go into prices slower)

The same could potentially be said about the difference in momentum across asset classes.

Is there any evidence? Any references/ thoughts welcome.

Comment: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1800754

Comment: @assylias: Interesting. So the evidence in Australia is that there is more momentum in illiquid stocks. Any studies related to institutional holdings, anyone?

Comment: No the opposite: they find a (small) momentum effect in liquid stocks but an "anti-momentum" (mean reverting?) effect in illiquid stocks.

Comment: @assylias: Sorry, typo.

Comment: @assylias could you type the name of the paper as an answer - so that it can be found later one even if the linkt dies

Comment: @Probilitator Feel free to use the link if you want to answer in more details.

Comment: okey thanks - I have asked a friend of mine who is into statistical arbitrage to look into it. To make sure your comment stays link-indepent: "The Impact of Liquidity and Transaction Costs on the 52-Week High Momentum Strategy in Australia"